# How to print the datatype of a cell present in excel using night watch?

Tags: excel, cell, percentage, nightwatch.js, custom-data-type

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diuKY.png)

I need to print the value of the excel cells (attached).
expected: I should receive values - "0%" and "100%"
current: I receive values - "0" and "100"

Comment: are you trying to read test data from excel or why do you need nightwatch to read data?

Comment: For testing purpose, I need to test whether a particular range of cell has dataType "%" or not

Answer (score 0):

I think this is beyond the capabilities of nightwatch you need to write node program for this.

Comment: can you guide me through it?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of nightwatchjs is to work with browser during e2e automation. The scenario you are looking for is something out of its scope but is possible by using some npm package like [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs).

They have good documentation as well [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#value-types). You can interact with a workbook object and modify it as you wish.